# How to fix data truncation issue for columns in table variable with Datatype as varchar(max)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql

I have a table variable with a column of type `varchar(max)`. I am storing resultset of another query in this table variable. The length of the result that I get on querying this table is 7870. I wanted this result to be transposed using comma separator and before each value, I had to append "t." But this resulted in data exceeding 8000 so anything after that is getting truncated even if the datatype of the column is `varchar(max)`

Since datatype is `varchar(max)` so I don't want data to be truncated so tried setting property Set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF before inserting data to table variable But still no success.

```
DECLARE @FormattedMainResult VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @CommonColumns TABLE (FinalColumns VARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @CommonColumns
    SELECT main.AllColumnsMain AS CommonColumns
    FROM [dbo].[Staging] Stg
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Target] main ON Stg.AllColumnsStg = main.AllColumnsMain

SELECT SUM(LEN(FinalColumns)) AS MaxLen_FinalCommonColumns  
FROM @CommonColumns  -- 7870

SELECT * 
FROM @CommonColumns
```

**Output:**

```
Final Columns
---------------
John
Carl
Scott
Rick

SELECT @FormattedMainResult = (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                   STUFF((SELECT ',' + 't.' +u.FinalColumns
                                          FROM
                                              (SELECT FinalColumns 
                                               FROM @CommonColumns) u
                                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS userlist)  

SELECT SUM(LEN(@FormattedMainResult)) AS MaxLen_posttranspose  -- 8230 so data is truncated
PRINT @FormattedMainResult
```

**Output**

```
t.John,t.Carl,t.Sc
```

Actual result from `@FormattedMainResult`:

```
t.John,t.Carl,t.Sc (data truncated)
```

Expected result from `@FormattedMainResult`:

```
t.John,t.Carl,t.Scott,....,t.Rick (no truncation)
```

**Update**

Now I am facing issue while executing Insert into statement which I get from select query result.

Example,

```
Declare @Result nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @FormattedStgResult varchar(MAX)
DECLARE  @joinCondition VARCHAR(MAX)='s.Id=t.Id'

SET @Result = ''
SET @Result = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME('vjtest') +'.'+ QUOTENAME('dbo') +'.'+ QUOTENAME('Staging') +' (' + @FormattedStgResult + ')  
 SELECT ' + @FormattedMainResult + 
' FROM '+ QUOTENAME('vjtest') +'.'+ QUOTENAME('dbo')+'.'+QUOTENAME('Target') + ' t
 LEFT JOIN '+ QUOTENAME('vjtest') +'.'+QUOTENAME('dbo')+'.'+QUOTENAME('Staging')+ ' s
 ON ' + @joinCondition + 
' WHERE s.UniqueId IS NULL'

Exec(@Result)
```

@FormattedMainResult is same as old code which will have values with prefix "t."  -> t.Id,t.Name,1,....,t.Rootpid

@FormattedStgResult has the same result as @FormattedMainResult only difference there is no prefix "t." -> Id,Name,IsDelete,...Rootpid

This does generate correct Insert statement with expected columns but when it is executed in Exec(@Result) it says 0 rows affected. However, when that same query I execute manually it does show 3 rows affected.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: To clarify: Using `QuoteName( u.FinalColumns )` avoids surprises when getting column names from a possibly untrustworthy source, or just creatively named columns. Applying `QuoteName()` to `'dbo'` doesn't offer much benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The T-SQL comment in your code proves the actual variable length is 8230 characters. The issue is that [`PRINT` is limited to 8000 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql) and will truncate excess characters.

Use `SELECT @FormattedMainResult;` to return the entire value, unless truncated by SSMS according to max column length in results query option. Keep `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` unless you have legacy code that requires non-ISO SQL behavior.

Comment: Thanks, @Dan Guzman with SELECT my complete data is printed in the console. However, Result which I get from FormattedMainResult going forward in the process will be an Insert Into statement. So this Insert into Statment is printed in the console now perfectly but when I do EXEC(FormattedMainResult) it does not give an error but does not do the insert which it was supposed to.

Comment: @VikasJ, it's difficult to troubleshoot code we cannot see. Add the relevant code that builds the `INSERT` statement to your question.

Comment: I have added code in the update section of my question. For your reference.

Comment: @VikasJ, the added code is not assigning a value to `@FormattedStgResult` so `@Result` value with the SQL statement will be `NULL` and the execute will be a no-op.

Comment: Can you please help me here, from what I understand I am assigning the whole Insert into statement which includes other local variables results 
 FormattedStgResult to Result variable and then execute the complete thing. The values in FormattedStgResult  &  FormattedMainResult are already assigned. before calling Insert Into statement.

Comment: @VikasJ, the code declares the variable (`DECLARE @FormattedStgResult varchar(MAX)`) but never assigns a value so it will be always be `NULL` and cause `@Result` to be `NULL` as well.